# Is there a "%"-symbol for Space in string.format()?

Tags: java, string.format, format-string

For new line the symbol is "%n"; how about space, is there a symbol for it?

I've searched for it on various websites but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would just use a space, `" "`, and that's it. No magic here for this one.

for example:

```
String text = "%4d: %04x%n";  // note the space
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  System.out.println(text, i, i);
}
```

---

You comment:

> I am looking for the equivalent symbol mate.

There is no equivalent symbol, and there's no need for one. This is likely why your Google search has yielded no fruit.

Comment: I am looking for the equivalent symbol mate.

Comment: @user3371414 Only thing I can think of would be the `"\u0020"`, but what was posted is correct...

Comment: @user3371414 Space *is* a "symbol" (just one that is normally displayed as empty space, but as some editors show this is not universal).

Comment: cheers then mate. I just thought that there might be something equivalent to %n but thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There's no *equivalent symbol* because there would be no use. The `%n` [prints a platform-dependent newline character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) (`\r`, `\r\n`, `\n`), but there is no such a thing as a platform-dependent *"space"*, so you just use a `" "` in your format string.

Answer (score 1):

The % symbol introduces an argument descriptor.

If you're going to use space as an argument, the argument descriptor would be %s, just as it is for any other string.

Otherwise the symbol for space is a space.